# Realloc doen't work in For Loop

Tags: c, realloc

I try to reallocate an integer array on increase of array size. The array size increases till seven elements over which it gets in to error. The code snippet is provided below

```
*#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int number, i,count = 0;
        int *a;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
        a = malloc(sizeof(int)*number);

    printf("Factors of %d are: ", number);
    for(i=1; i <= number; ++i)
    {
        if (number%i == 0)
        {
                a[count] = i;
                printf(" %d %d \n",count,a[count]);
                a =  realloc(a,(count+1)*sizeof(int));
                count++;
        }
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}*
```

Comment: You can't use `realloc()` properly if you use its return value to overwrite its input pointer.  What happens if it fails?

Comment: Not sure why you're using `realloc`. The first `malloc` allocates more space than needed.

Comment: You are not testing the return of `malloc()` and `realloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

First loop:

```
count == 0
a[count] = i
a = realloc(1 int)
count++
```

Second loop:

```
count == 1
a[count] = i  /* OUT OF BOUNDS */
```

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or [ASAN](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) would catch this error right away. Without them, it doesn't get noticed for a while purely by coincidence.

---

```
$ cc -g -o test test.c
$ valgrind ./test
==25080== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25080== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.       
==25080== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info    
==25080== Command: ./test                                                       
==25080==                                                                       
Enter a positive integer: 4                                                     
Factors of 4 are:  0 1                                                          
==25080== Invalid write of size 4                                               
==25080==    at 0x4006D0: main (test.c:16)                                      
==25080==  Address 0x51db914 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd         
==25080==    at 0x4C2D13F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)                                                                     
==25080==    by 0x40071A: main (test.c:18)                                      
==25080==                                                                       
==25080== Invalid read of size 4                                                
==25080==    at 0x4006E6: main (test.c:17)                                      
==25080==  Address 0x51db914 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd         
==25080==    at 0x4C2D13F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==25080==    by 0x40071A: main (test.c:18)
==25080== 
 1 2 
 2 4 
==25080== 
==25080== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25080==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25080==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 2,088 bytes allocated
==25080== 
==25080== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25080== 
==25080== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25080== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

```
$ clang -fsanitize=address -g -o test test.c
$ ./test
Enter a positive integer: 5
Factors of 5 are:  0 1 
=================================================================
==23697==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000eff4 at pc 0x0000004ffdec bp 0x7ffc641c5eb0 sp 0x7ffc641c5ea8
WRITE of size 4 at 0x60200000eff4 thread T0
    #0 0x4ffdeb  (/home/dlin/test+0x4ffdeb)
    #1 0x7faaee64f510  (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x20510)
    #2 0x4186a9  (/home/dlin/test+0x4186a9)

0x60200000eff4 is located 0 bytes to the right of 4-byte region [0x60200000eff0,0x60200000eff4)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4c83d0  (/home/dlin/test+0x4c83d0)
    #1 0x4ffe8d  (/home/dlin/test+0x4ffe8d)
    #2 0x7faaee64f510  (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x20510)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (/home/dlin/test+0x4ffdeb) 
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff9da0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff9db0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff9dc0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff9dd0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff9de0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x0c047fff9df0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa[04]fa
  0x0c047fff9e00: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff9e10: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff9e20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff9e30: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff9e40: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Heap right redzone:      fb
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack partial redzone:   f4
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==23697==ABORTING
```